# Sending params in http request library

Tags: node.js, express

So this question is related to a popular express library (I think) called request https://github.com/request/request

I've been scrolling through its README.md and I'm either blind or I'm having a hard time finding a way to send params in a GET request. 
The api service I'm using tells me to

```
"send a GET request to the /1/login endpoint with username 
and password as URL-encoded parameters:"
```

I don't believe I should be using streaming, forms, http authentication, custom http Headers, OAuth Signing, proxies, Unix Domain SOckets, TLS/SSL protocol. Do I encode it and send it as query parameters? which doesn't seem safe because I'm using the service for logging in users. *Crossing fingers that this isn't a dumb question*

Comment: Have you tried sending is as query parameters, because it looks like you need to do that from what the error says. You can use encodeURI(username) to get the encoded parameter

Comment: it also looks like you can send parameters as the second argument of router like this: router.get(url, { username: 'something', password: 'something'})

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to send query string parameters with the request library use the `qs` option:

```
request({
  method: 'GET',
  uri:'https://google.com/search',
  qs: {
    q: 'search query',
  }
}, function(err, res, body){
  console.log(body)
})
```

You are correct to be cautious about credentials.
IMO for most applications you can use HTTPS throughout your site, POST username/password as a form body or JSON, and rely on TLS to protect the data in transit.
Mixing HTTP and HTTPS is risky, e.g. an HTTP page containing a link to `https://domain.com/login` is vulnerable to the "sslstrip" attack (where an attacker poisons the http code, replacing the link with `http://attacker.com/?spoof=https://domain.com/login`.)

I advise against making (*in-browser*) GET requests with username/password in querystring because they'll show up in the address bar and someone can look over the user's shoulder.